# MongoDB or CouchDB - fit for production?

Tags: database, mongodb, couchdb

I was wondering if anyone can tell me if *[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home)* or *[CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)* are ready for a **production** environment.

I'm now looking at these storage solutions (I'm favouring MongoDB at the moment), however these projects are quite young and so I foresee that I'm going to have to work quite hard to convince my manager that we should adopt this new technology.

What I'd like to know is:

1. Who is using MongoDB or CouchDB today in a production environment?
2. How are you using MongoDB/CouchDB?
3. What problems (if any) did you come across when you adopted this new storage mechanism (and how did you overcome them)?
4. How did you deal with any migration issues that you had to deal with?
5. Do you have any good/bad experiences with either of these solutions that you'd like to share?

Comment: Looking through the answers, I didn't really find what I was looking for.

Since both databases are so much alike, which one should I chose? What are the benefits of either one of them?
For what kind of application should I chose which?

Would be nice if someone could answer those questions.

Comment: It really depends on how they will be used. The lack of transactions is troubling for many environments, yet perfectly fine for others. Also it is fundamentally difficult to "back up" a distributed database, although the argument is that data persistence is ensured through replication across multiple shards.

Comment: @pauluss86 I think you should probably add the disclaimer to pauluss86's link that the author (Emin) is actually from a competitor to MongoDB (Hyperdex) - so just a *slight* bias there. To be really fair, there's a corresponding response on InfoQ from MongoDB here - http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/02/MongoDB-Fault-Tolerance-Broken

Comment: @victorhooi true, but it remains a valid concern in my opinion. There's also a follow-up to the InfoQ response: [link](http://hackingdistributed.com/2013/02/07/10gen-response/). Personally, I'm not too convinced by Mongo's defense. In any case, I recommend anyone to read up on the issue (both sides) before choosing a database.

Comment: This says it all http://db-engines.com/en/ranking
MongoDB is gaining ground day by day and is most popular Document Store on the web

Answer (score 267, accepted):

I'm the CTO of 10gen (developers of MongoDB) so I'm a bit biased, but I also manage a few sites that are using MongoDB in production.

[businessinsider](http://www.businessinsider.com) has been using mongo in production for over a year now.  They are using it for everything from users and blog posts, to every image on the site.

[shopwiki](http://shopwiki.com) is using it for a few things including real time analytics and a caching layer. They are doing over 1000 writes per second to a fairly large database.

If you go to the [mongodb Production Deployments page](http://www.mongodb.org/about/production-deployments/) you'll see some people who are using mongo in production.

If you have any questions about the scale or scope of production deployments, post on our user list and we'll be more than happy to help.

Comment: here's the link http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Deployments

Comment: would you mind make mongodb run with v8 as default. and mongodb eat too much memory for poor guys who using a VPS with 512M memory.

Comment: You can have AC(i)D at least - atomicity because single master writer, consistency because you have per-document consistency, durability because you can specify how many writes are needed before ACKing write, e.g. how many other nodes need get the data before ACKing it.

Comment: +1 for the links. amazing how many ppl using mongodb in production

Comment: Looks like a lot of things have changed in the past 5 years. That list is massive! :)

Answer (score 110):

The [BBC](http://BBC.co.uk) and [meebo.com](http://meebo.com) use CouchDB in production and so does one of my clients.
Here is a list of other people using Couch: [CouchDB in the wild](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CouchDB_in_the_wild)

The major challenge is to know how to organize your documents and stop thinking in terms of relational data.

Comment: Actually for me the major challenge is going back if you need to. Once you remove "relational constraints" from your mind it is difficult to go back. :)

Answer (score 44):

[SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/) uses MongoDB. See [this presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/MongoDB-at-SourceForge) or [read here](http://compoundthinking.com/blog/index.php/2009/07/18/serving-developers-and-users-at-sourceforge/).

Comment: What are they using it for? Or how are they using it?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but maybe someone will look at it again. Here is a presentation by a SourceForge dev about how they employ MongoDO: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/MongoDB-at-SourceForge

Answer (score 34):

We are running CouchDB as a replacemant for MySQL for our shops (70.0000 items/shop, a total of 4 million attributes of all items, cross connections between items).

Our goals were:

1. Easy replication from a master-db to several clients with different documents.
2. Fast pre-calculated data like "how many parts do I have with this attribute and that filter, fitting to those conditions"

facts:

1. Our shops are now running much faster than with MySQL (and mysql-database needed additionaly  1-3 days of pre-calculating (so updating was twice a month), making the data ready for product counting and filtering, CouchDB needs 5 hours, so we could update product data every night)
2. Setting up (filtered) data distribution & backups to the shop nodes is fast and easy

but also:

1. Understanding map/reduce and the limits of not having joins is quite hard
2. No operation on data like "delete where" or "update where" without external programs
3. Replication works well, unless there is a problem; then it's really hard to find out what was the reason (for beginners)
4. The installation of CouchDB without binaries (yes there are a some in the wild, but not for every OS/version) could be hard, if you are not a Linux geek. But the CouchDB Community is helpful (#couchdb), and luckily there are companies out there (cloudant, iriscouch) that offer services from free to big business.
5. CouchDB is moving forward, so there are a lot of changes (improvements) going on that might change they way you work. But basic things remain stable.

As a result:
MySQL as a database for data creation and maintaining is reliable and easy to understand and handle. I think we will not change this. 
But I also don't want to miss the power of CouchDB views and the ease of replication setup.

Production couches sometimes caused trouble after months of work due to misconfiguration and forgotten logrotates (view building takes too long or hangs, replication stops), but never lost data, and always could be easily reset.

Comment: 70 000 or 700 000 items per shop? also, has anything changed since you wrote the post? some missing features implemented maybe?

Answer (score 27):

I am using CouchDB in production. Currently it stores all those 'optional' fields that weren't in the original DB schema. And right now I am thinking about moving all data to CouchDB.

It's quite a risky step, I admit. Firstly, because it's not v1.0 yet. And secondly, because it is drivespace-hungry. By my calculations, CouchDB file (with indexes) is ~30 times larger than MySQL database with the same rows. 
But I am pretty sure it will work out just fine.

Comment: Well, it didn't work out at all. I got rid of couchdb after a couple of months.

Comment: @aetheria: It didn't handle the load. Plus we had so much writes that we'd need to compact it every hour or so. CouchDB is not for write-heavy apps.

Comment: Thanks. Am I right that it's updates to existing documents that's the problem? i.e. writing new documents is OK, but updating leaves unused garbage in the file. Is that correct?

Comment: IIRC, even new writes were not too performant. Too much disk seeks with this double-header approach.

Comment: Argh. It's so hard to know what database to choose! Did you go back to MySQL or move to a different NoSQL?

Comment: @aetheria: back to mysql and then to mongo. Had a fair share of problems everywhere. :)

Answer (score 18):

CouchDB 0.11 (released at the end of March) is a feature-freeze release for 1.0. This means we'll be maintaining compatibility with the current API for 1.0, so now is a good time to take another look at CouchDB if you haven't in a while.

The [CouchDB 0.11 source code release is available here.](http://couchdb.apache.org/downloads.html) There are [binary installers and other goodies linked here.](http://www.couch.io/downloads)

Answer (score 17):

I don't know anything about MongoDB, but from the [CouchDB FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Frequently_asked_questions#is_couchdb_ready_for_production):

> **Is CouchDB Ready for Production?**
>
> Yes, see [InTheWild](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/InTheWild) for a partial list of projects using CouchDB. Another good overview is [CouchDB Case Studies](http://www.couchone.com/case-studies)

Also, some links:

- [Re: Current CouchDB state?](http://osdir.com/ml/couchdb-user/2009-01/msg00015.html)
- [SimpleDB, CouchDB and Other "NEW" Data Stores - Feedback](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?biz.5.727383.8)

Comment: This is old news: Now the link says "Yes, see InTheWild for a partial list of projects using CouchDB. Another good overview is CouchDB Case Studies"

Comment: @J Chris A: Of course it's old, I posted this a year and a half ago. :)

Answer (score 16):

We use couchdb in production and have since just before the project went under the Apache umbrella.

We use it to store everything that we might otherwise use a dbms, plus all sorts of unstructured data.  Personally, I really like how you can just throw all sorts of data into it and use the views to cull what you don't need depending on the situation.

The hardest part was moving away from the dbms mindset.  We wrote our own migration utils when the storage format changed just to be safe, so that wasn't really a problem.

We haven't had any negative experiences yet, but then again we haven't had the setup under any kind of huge load.  I *think* things would work pretty well since we have two slave type servers that replicate from a single master server that gets all of the writes.  I'm pretty sure that we don't have to do it that way for replication to work correctly, but it's how we set it up in the beginning and it stuck.

Answer (score 13):

We use CouchDB to store mobile inbound and outbound messages and to report on this traffic via some custom views that I wrote.  The front-end is written in Python.  We did not have any real technical issues, and it has been running since the end of December.  The only hurdle I encountered was initially thinking in terms of MapReduce, but once I learned how to do that, everything else went smoothly.

Answer (score 9):

We are currently using MongoDB in production as the caching layer as well as storage engine for product importing and manipulating product data. We are an eCommerce company managing over two million products (100+ million attributes), spanning 10+ distributors and without MongoDB, this task would be nearing impossible.

Comment: How reliable has mongoDB proven to be for you? + How well have replication worked in real life?

Comment: We implement the replica set topology running 1.6.(not sure what the minor version is off hand). So far the only issue we encountered is apparently when a disk runs out of space, even with save writes enabled, no flags are raised. So just make sure you have PLENTY of space!

Comment: Reliability however has been phenomenal, surprisingly as good as we had hoped. No problems with crashing as of yet- Although this is somewhat of a new implementation.

Answer (score 1):

We are currently using mongodb as an file storage service for our collaboration over LAN.
Also, projects like [trello](http://trello.com) are using mongodb as their backend datastore.
I have used couchdb earlier, but not in production capacity.

Answer (score 0):

We are using MongoDB in production in our mobile backend service namely [Netmera.](http://netmera.com/) We are using it to store all user and content data.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using CouchDB in production for almost 2 years now. There's no migration work as the project started of directly with CouchDB implementation. It serves as a database that stores the data of a single electronic product from beginning till packaging.

Since we are selling sensor with a demand on high accuracy, we do a lot of test at different stage and all these will be stored into one document on CouchDB.

There's some learning curve that I learnt from my experience, which is to make full use of the views (or also known as permanent views). Views should be "small filter" of a fraction of the Database that will be called often.

My CouchDB databse is not as crazy as other gigantic company. But so far, I'm still doing fine. Currently I'm having 24000 documents at 700MB.

Feature from CouchDB that I like is 'replication', 'store revisions of a document'.

I'd read a lot of good reviews on MongoDB and I will want to try it if there's a chance.

Answer (score 0):

We are using mongodb in production for

www.beachfront.io - close to 5k write request per sec
www.beachfrontbuilder.com - 500 read/write request per sec, maintain 10m users data & olap.

The only challenge faced around archiving of data, we overcome by implementing our custom component.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already accepted answer but now a days one more **NoSQL DB** is in trend for many of its great features. It is `Couchbase`; which runs as `CouchbaseLite` on mobile platform and `Couchbase Server` on your server side.

**Here is some of main features of Couchbase Lite.**

Couchbase Lite is a lightweight, document-oriented (NoSQL), syncable database engine suitable for embedding into mobile apps.

**Lightweight means:**

Embedded—the database engine is a library linked into the app, not a separate server process.
Small code size—important for mobile apps, which are often downloaded over cell networks.
Quick startup time—important because mobile devices have relatively slow CPUs.
Low memory usage—typical mobile data sets are relatively small, but some documents might have large multimedia attachments.
Good performance—exact figures depend on your data and application, of course.

**Document-oriented means:**

Stores records in flexible JSON format instead of requiring predefined schemas or normalization.
Documents can have arbitrary-sized binary attachments, such as multimedia content.
Application data format can evolve over time without any need for explicit migrations.
MapReduce indexing provides fast lookups without needing to use special query languages.

**Syncable means:**

Any two copies of a database can be brought into sync via an efficient, reliable, proven replication algorithm.
Sync can be on-demand or continuous (with a latency of a few seconds).
Devices can sync with a subset of a large database on a remote server.
The sync engine supports intermittent and unreliable network connections.
Conflicts can be detected and resolved, with app logic in full control of merging.
Revision trees allow for complex replication topologies, including server-to-server (for multiple data centers) and peer-to-peer, without data loss or false conflicts.
Couchbase Lite provides native APIs for seamless iOS (Objective-C) and Android (Java) development. In addition, it includes the Couchbase Lite Plug-in for PhoneGap, which enables you to build iOS and Android apps that you develop by using familiar web-application programming techniques and the PhoneGap mobile development framework.

You can explore more on [Couchbase Lite](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/cbl-concepts/)

and  [Couchbase Server](http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-server/overview)

This is going to the next big thing.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking production,  seamless failover/recovery  both require a baby sitter 
1- Couchbase, there is no seamless failover/recovery, manual intervention is required. 
rebalancing takes too much time, too much risk if more than one node get lost.

2- Mongo with shards, data recovery from loosing a config server, is not an easy task

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe](http://Adobe.com) is using **MongoDB** for their upcoming release of *Adobe Experience Manager* (formerly *Day CQ*) as the core DB engine.

Several client's at the agency I work at are using **CouchDB** on projects for large clients.

Both are great and viable DBs, in my opinion.  :)

Answer (score -2):

Here's a list of production deployed sites with mongoDB

- **The New Yorks Times**: Using it in a form-building application for photo submissions. Mongo's lack of schema gives producers the ability to define any combination of custom form fields.
- **SourceForge**: is used for back-end storage on the SourceForge front pages, project pages, and download pages for all projects.
- **Bit.ly**
- **Etsy**
- **IGN**: powers IGN’s real-time traffic analytics and RESTful Content APIs.
- **Justin.tv**: powers Justin.tv's internal analytics tools for virality, user retention, and general usage stats that out-of-the-box solutions can't provide.
- **Posterous**
- **Intuit**
- **Foursquare**: Sharded Mongo databases are used for most data at foursquare.
- **Business Insider**: Using it since the beginning of 2008. All of the site's data, including posts, comments, and even the images, are stored on MongoDB.
- **Github**: is used for an internal reporting application.
- **Examiner**: migrated their site from Cold Fusion and SQL Server to Drupal 7 and MongoDB.
- **Grooveshark**: currently uses Mongo to manage over one million unique user sessions per day.
- **Buzzfeed**
- **Discus**
- **Evite**: Used for analytics and quick reporting.
- **Squarespace**
- **Shutterfly**: is used for various persistent data storage requirements within Shutterfly. MongoDB helps Shutterfly build an unrivaled service that enables deeper, more personal relationships between customers and those who matter most in their lives.
- **Topsy**
- **Sharethis**
- **Mongohq**: provides a hosting platform for MongoDB and also uses MongoDB as the back-end for its service. Our hosting centers page provides more information about MongoHQ and other MongoDB hosting options.

and more...

Extracted from:
http://lineofthought.com/tools/mongodb

You can check other databases or tools there too.

Comment: Added big part of the list to the post

Answer (score -6):

MongoDB has some issues with licensing to businesses, I am not sure of the details but our legal department told us in no certain terms that we were not allowed to use MongoDB in any of our products.

Comment: while you have not specified the exact issues with licensing, there is nothing wrong with MongoDB licensing http://www.mongodb.org/about/licensing/ It uses the AGPL license which may be the cause of concerns in your legald department, but they state that any DB client is separate work. "we promise that your client application which uses the database is a separate work. To facilitate this, the mongodb.org supported drivers (the part you link with your application) are released under Apache license, which is copyleft free."